# RegEx to match expression even if it is not 100% the same

Tags: php, regex, string

How would you write a regular expression pattern that matches a string even if it is 90% accurate?

For example:

```
$search_string = "Two years in,&nbsp;the <a href='site.com'>company</a> has expanded to 35 cities, five of which are outside the U.S. "

$subject = "Two years in,the company has expanded to 35 cities, five of which are outside the U.S."
```

The end result is that the `$search_string` matches the `$subject` and returns true even though they are not 100% the same.

Comment: RegEx is a pattern matching algorithm, not a pattern nearly-matching algorithm. Use wildcards for unknowns but generally you're barking up the wrong tree

Comment: Why does everyone seem to be conditioned to repeat don't use regular expressions to parse HTML blablabla.. We are talking about a miniscule amount of HTML and doing simple operations on it. You want to tell me that there is no way to do what i want ?  What will be your solution then?

Comment: Split on html tags and entities, then join with `.*?`.Use this `(?i)[&%](?:[a-z]+|(?:\#(?:[0-9]+|x[0-9a-f]+));)|<(?:script(?:\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+)?\s*>[\S\s]*?</script\s*|(?:/?[\w:]+\s*/?)|(?:[\w:]+\s+(?:(?:(?:"[\S\s]*?")|(?:'[\S\s]*?'))|(?:[^>]*?))+\s*/?)|\?[\S\s]*?\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\S\s]*?)|(?:\[CDATA\[[\S\s]*?\]\])|(?:--[\S\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\S\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\S\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\S\s]*?))))>`

Comment: @Dagon - Check the top answer. We need a proper moderation on this site to clean up false knowledge dissipated by ppl like you

Comment: @user3857924 you should discuss your issues with how S.O runs on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) - that's what it is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have some optional parts on the regex pattern. For example:

```
$search_string = "A tiny little bear";
$regex = "A ([a-zA-Z]+)? little bear";
```

The **?** character there says that the group before it goes optional, and the **[a-zA-Z]+** indicates there will be one or more letters inside it.

Thus, using *preg_match* you can get a validation not 100% restrictive.

Comment: Thanks that looks promising

Comment: Is the following valid then? $regex= "Two years in,(&nbsp;)?the (<a href='site.com'>company</a>)? has expanded to 35 cities, five of which are outside the U.S."

Comment: Yes, it is, but be careful with the empty spaces between characters!

Comment: Ideally, I am looking for a pattern which looks like that: "$search_string, optional characters: &nbsp;, etc.". If that is possible ?

Comment: It will be dificult to get any appearances of *&nbsp;* in the string. Regex works with position and order of characters, not with things like "look for any appearance of this set of characters...". If you need that, maybe you have to play a little more with the PHP string functions, and creating a regex pattern for each string the user creates. Something like, to be simple: $regex = modifyString($userInputString);

Answer (score 1):

in case any one comes around looking for the *right* way to do it

```
   $search_string = "Two years in,&nbsp;the <a href='site.com'>company</a> has expanded to 35 cities, five of which are outside the U.S. ";

$subject = "Two years in,the company has expanded to 35 cities, five of which are outside the U.S.";

  similar_text ($search_string,$subject,$sim);

  echo 'text is: ' .round($sim). '% similar';
```

result:

**text is:85% similar**

you can use the result to determine what value is a match in your particular circumstances like so:

```
similar_text($search_string,$subject,$sim);

    if($sim >=85){

    echo 'MATCH';

    }
```

Comment: That's pretty cool. `similar_text,levenshtein ..` Where can I find out how it is done?

Comment: the php manual- then the php source, dont ask me how the maths works :-)

Comment: This is ok if you are comparing against a single string. Here, I am searching through a whole html page

Comment: any more pertinent information you have left out of the question?

Answer (score 1):

Just for grins, I tried this out using Perl.

*All the warnings about using regex to parse html apply:

(Should not use on html).*

This will split the *Search* string on either html or entities or whitespace.
After that, the parts are joined with `.*?` using the modifiers `(?is)`.

This is not a true partial matching substring regex because
*it requires all the parts to exist*.
This does overcome the distance or content between them however.
Possibly, with a little algorithm work, it could be tweaked in such
a way that parts are optional, in the form of clustering.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $search_string = "Two years in,&nbsp;the <a href='site.com'>company</a> has expanded to 35 cities, five of which are outside the U.S. ";

my $subject = "Two years in,the company has expanded to 35 cities, five of which are outside the U.S.";


## Trim leading/trailing whitespace from $search_string

  $search_string =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;

## Split the $search_string on html tags or entities or whitespaces ..

  my @SearchParts = split m~

    \s+|
    (?i)[&%](?:[a-z]+|(?:\#(?:[0-9]+|x[0-9a
    -f]+)));|<(?:script(?:\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'
    [\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+)?\s*>[\S\s]*?</script
    \s*|(?:/?[\w:]+\s*/?)|(?:[\w:]+\s+(?:(?:
    (?:"[\S\s]*?")|(?:'[\S\s]*?'))|(?:[^>]*?
    ))+\s*/?)|\?[\S\s]*?\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE
    [\S\s]*?)|(?:\[CDATA\[[\S\s]*?\]\])|(?:-
    -[\S\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\S\s]*?)|(?:ENTI
    TY[\S\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\S\s]*?))))>

  ~x, $search_string;

## Escape the metacharacters from SearchParts

  @SearchParts = grep { $_ = quotemeta } @SearchParts;

## Join the SearchParts into a regex 

  my $rx = '(?si)(?:' . ( join '.*?', @SearchParts ) . ')';

## Try to match SearchParts in the $subject 

  if ( $subject =~ /$rx/ )
  {
     print "Match in subject:\n'$&' \n";
  }
```

Output:

```
Match in subject:
'Two years in,the company has expanded to 35 cities, five of which are outside the U.S.'
```

**edit:**
As a side note, each element of @SearchParts *could* be further split//
once again (on each character), joining with `.*?`.
This would get into the realm of a *true* partial match.
Not quite there though as each character is required to match.
The order is maintained, but each one would have to be optional.
Usually, without capture groups, there is no way to tell the percentage
of actual letter's matched.
If you were to use *Perl* however, it's fairly easy to count in
regex *Code* construct `(?{{..}})` where a counter can be incremented.
I guess, at that point it becomes non-portable. Better to use C++.